# Closing a system dialog fails

Tags: java, android

I am executing a ussd code in my android application in this function

```
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
String ussdCode = "*" + "199" + "*" + "8" + "*" + "0897067547" + Uri.encode("#");
switch (getResultCode())
{
case Activity.RESULT_OK:
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + ussdCode))); 
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS));

break;
case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
}
}
```

I am able to execute the ussd code but afterwards i am not able to close the ussd dialog.How may i go about closing the ussd dialog?.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  Its a dialog from another app, you can't close it.  Which is why the general rule is not to use USSD for anything in Android-  not only is it not portable across carriers, but there is no real USSD API-  you can just sort of kind of hack some of it together (not to mention that USSD is a hack itself that should die now that web services and data connections exist).